# Navbar in IE 10 floating left inspite of flexbox property justify-content:flex-end

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have basically the following site **[HERE](http://codeandcode.co/demo/Alfred/html/V2/activities.html)**, 
Now i have checked the header in IE 11 and IE 10 and on my system it looks like following:

[image]

**(above screen shot is what it should look like.)**
But on my bosses system it the navbar floats towards the left and overlapps the logo, basically the logo and the navbar are in a parent container and i have the following properties applied:

```
.main-nav > .container {
    height: 105px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

The logo is absolutely positioned and left aligned using the `left` property. Now why is it that on my bosses system the navbar floats to the leftor gets left aligned and does't honor  `justify-content: flex-end;` ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a prefix for the `justify-content` property. Remove all prefixes and run your CSS through here: https://autoprefixer.github.io/